# How to extend sharepoint survey

Tags: survey-list, survey

I want to extend the SharePoint survey to store more data. As start date, end date, target audience etc. Where can I keep these data? Obviously not as fields?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, if you create a field and set [Hidden property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.hidden.aspx) to `True`

```
<Field 
    Type="DateTime"  
    DisplayName="End Date" 
    Hidden="true"  />
```

then the field will not be displayed in a question form.

[image]

Comment: But fields will be repeating for each responses. right? I need to set start date only once for a survey.

Comment: That's right, in that case you could store addition metadata per List using, for example, Property Bag (SPList.RootFolder)